# The Network Security Key is not correct. Please try again

Tags: windows

I have installed Windows 8 64bit Preview on my spare machine on a separate partition from the Windows 7 64bit that is currently on this machine.

The Windows 7 64bit works perfectly, but when I boot to the Windows 8 64bit system I am unable to get access to the Internet or the HOMEGROUP on my main machine. The Windows 8 64bit system is "seeing" my connection but when I enter the Network Security Key (which works on the Windows 7 64bit system) I repeatedly get "The Network Security Key is not correct. Please try again"

Can anyone help?